# "Library not loaded" error after upgrade python with Homebrew

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, pipenv

I use pipenv to create virtualenv like this

```sh
pipenv --python /usr/local/bin/python3
```

After upgrade python with Homebrew, like python 3.7.2 to 3.7.3, active virtualenv with `pipenv shell`, and do anything with python will be error
like this

```sh
python3 --version
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xxx/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found
[1]    60198 abort      python3 --version
```

All I know about this is `/usr/local/bin/python3` is still there, run python on system level is good. Only call python in virtualenv will be wrong.

For now I have remove the virtualenvs and create it with pipenv again,
it will fix this.
But do these things will lost all pip packages, so I need to reinstall them again.

So, dose there have some smart way to solve this problem?
Or what is happen during Homebrew upgrade python?

Maybe this question looks stupid. But I have been confused for a long time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. The missing library is `.Python` which is a link that is at the top level of the virtual env (in your case `/Users/xxx/.local/share/virtualenvs/xxx-xxx`). If you go there and do `ls -l .Python` you can see that it points toward a specific homebrew Cellar directory (in my case `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python`). This directory was probably removed by the update (do `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python` to find out the new directory/version.

Remove the link and let it point to the new location, e.g. for me:
`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python .Python`

Comment: Thank you. Everyone else says to nuke your venv and start over after running brew inside a venv. This fixed it for me.